# How can I add a requirements of the gcc version when building a RPM package?

Tags: rpm

I am building an RPM package that includes some C++ API, and my package requires GCC version greater than 7.3.0 in the user environment in order for it to work properly.

So, is there a way to automatically check the version of GCC in the user's environment when the user performs an 'rpm -i' installation, and report an error directly at installation time if it doesn't meet the requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put in the spec file:

Requires: gcc > 7.3.0

See https://rpm-software-management.github.io/rpm/manual/dependencies.html

But I doubt that you really want to require gcc, because that is only needed when building packages and not in runtime.

For additional information see:

- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/C_and_C++/
- https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/#_dependency_types

Comment: Thanks! What I actually want to limit is the version of GNU C++ Standard Library (libstdc++.so), because too low a version will cause exceptions in my program at runtime.